# How to write testbench for digital circuits that output video/audio signal

Tags: verification

As far as I have seen, a testbench will provide some stimulus to a DUT and the output shall be compared with expected values. This is one way to verify.

Many digial circuits however, may produce more complex outputs for example if they output a video or audio signal. How to people write a testbench that is able to verify such a signal.

In other words, audio/video signal may be have a lot of data in it. Do we need to look at it from a higher level when we simulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testbenches can take stimulus from files and write the result to files.

store the input audio/video data in a file (without compression) and use this as the stimuli. store the results in another file . you may have to verify the result manually by playing/reading the output file.

Implementing and testing on an FPGA would be better as the simulation can take time.

Answer (score 1):

We compare to a c model for what you describe.  The c model was made first and represents the block that takes digital video samples and converts them to analog output.  That output being samples to our d/a.

We take the c model as golden and compare it's output to the output of the up block in the testbench.

This is followed up with real world testing using a custom fpga development system.

That sounds like what you'd want if you are doing a video or analog block.  Now there are things like [verilog-ams](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog-AMS). That integrate verilog and analog simulation but I've never gotten involved in that.

Comment: A lot of people use a Matlab model to generate reference data for a testbench.

Comment: Yeah is should have included that a lot of the c model comes from Matlab.